# Import / Pull Google+ photos into external website

Tags: php, import, web, google-plus, photos

I need to enable visitors to my website to sign in with Google+ (this much I can do) and then import their photos from Google+ into the website. Have Googled this and can't find anything. It is fairly straight forward with Facebook. Does anyone know of any good tutorials that cover this or a good starting point?

Comment: Aren't the Google+ pictures actually just on picasa?  Might try going though that API. https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol

Comment: Yes. Use the Picasa Web API.